# jumping indices of values in buffer

Tags: linux, buffer, iio

I am currently testing some things with an accelerometer and its iio buffer and there is something that confuses me.
The sensor does have four different scan elements: `x`, `y`, `z` and a `timestamp`.
The indices of those values are:

`x = 0`, `y = 1`, `z = 2` and `time = 3`. So far so good.
If I enable all available scan elements the order of the entries is set according to the description.

everything enabled:

```
0000010 f758 011c 3f64 c0b0 be90 0bfe 499f 0004
0000020 f724 0134 3f58 c0b0 3f2f 10ab 499f 0004
```

But once I have gaps, for example if I disable the scan element for `y`, the `z` value jumps onto index 1 and my buffer looks like this:

`x`, `z` and `time`:

```
0000010 f720 3f70 0000 0000 722a 5c13 4946 0004
0000020 f728 3f74 0000 0000 0958 60c0 4946 0004
```

`z` and `time`:

```
0000010 3f6c 0000 0000 0000 ca0b 6ef1 48be 0004
0000020 3f44 0000 0000 0000 edf7 739e 48be 0004
```

only `x` and `z`:

```
0000010 f720 3f48 f748 3f54 f744 3f5c f75c 3f68
0000020 f750 3f78 f738 3f80 f718 3f64 f700 3f50
```

I could not find further information on this but I am a bit confused and surprised that the scan elements do not respect their given index once the timestamp is activated **and** there is an index gap. Is this the normal behavior or is this some stuff that the current sensor driver mixes up?

Comment: Which kernel version you are using? It was recently a big refactoring inside IIO subsystem to make sure timestamp is always aligned.

Comment: We are currently on verion 4.19.0.
I am just wondering if this is normal behavior or a bug in the sensor driver

Comment: Can you reproduce this on the latest vanilla (v5.14-rc6)? And I'm wondering why you use **0**, when v4.19.y stable is nowadays at **204**.

Comment: Since I was not in involed in chosing the kernel version I am not totally aware of the reasons for that choice. I am sure there are some, but I did not deal with this. I will have a look if I can test it on the latest vanilla and I will let you know